# UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath method is not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

`cellForItemAtIndexPath` is not called. Everything is normal I think
what is problem?

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewCell *cell=(UICollectionView *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.titleText.text=@"test";

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Have you set the delegate property of your collectionView?

Comment: you add this [self.collectionView reloadData]; in viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Actually you do not have to set the delegate properly, but rather the dataSource. Herefore you can either set it by code in the dataSource (which is probably the corresponding ViewController) so something like: self.collectionView.dataSource = self; (in case the collectionViews's variable is named "collectionView") or set in your interface builder's file. Select the UICollectionView object and show the connection inspector, here drag and drop the datasource to the view controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `viewDidLoad` method you probably want to add:

```
self.collectionView.delegate = self;
self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

easy as that.

Comment: I think the collectionView does not hold a reference to itself. Rather you mean the ViewController here, so it should be something like: self.collectionView.dataSource = self

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Coding on stackoverflow with no autocompletion sometimes gets me. Edited my answer!

Answer (score 2):

The `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` will not get called, if you don't provide the content size information to collection view. Override `collectionViewContentSize` and provide a size there, it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Completely i give you coding and follow that.You can get the solution

in .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate>
{
   NSMutableArray *imgArray;
   NSMutableArray *lblArray;
}


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collections;

@end
```

in .m

```
//If you prefer the custom cell for collection view,just import that

#import "customCell.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize collections;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    imgArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhone.jpg"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"iPad.jpg"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"iPod.jpg"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"iTV.jpg"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"iRing.jpg"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"iwatch.jpeg"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"iMove.jpg"],nil];

    lblArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"iPhone",@"iPad",@"iPod",@"iTV",@"iRing",@"iWatch",@"iMove", nil];

    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"customCell" bundle:nil];
    [collections registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


 //Create a Colletion view using UICollectionViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
     return [lblArray count];
 }

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";
    customCell *cell = (customCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.img_Collection.image = [imgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lbl_Collection.text = [lblArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
 }
```

NOTE : Put **BEARKPOINT** in CollectionView DataSource and Delegates Methods.Don't forget put breakpoint.

Answer (score -1):

There are many highlights for creating collectionView, like UICollectionViewFlowLayout, then implementation the dataSource function with no 0 return value.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```